# Request session initiated, successfully connected, then 401 for get request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm attempting to get a file from a website that requires a login, when I run the code through the command line, it runs perfectly and I get status codes of 200 for both the post and get method and I'm able to get the data I want. However, when I run it as a script, the get request fails (401).

I've tried using playing with timeouts, HTTPBasicAuth, and session.auth(username, password) with no success.

```
import requests


url = 'https://website.com'
credentials = {'user': 'my_name', 'password' : 'my_password'}
with requests.Session() as sesh:
    init = sesh.post(url+'/login', data=credentials)  #succeeds [200]
    print(init.status_code)
    xml = sesh.get(url+'/different/path')  #fails [401]
    if xml.status_code is 200:
        print(xml.content)
    else:
        print(xml.status_code)
```

Comment: There may be other headers and things that your browser passes that are done here. Can't tell without knowing the site

Comment: I've tried passing in all the necessary header information. The only thing I haven't done is try to manually send the cookies, but, in my limited understanding, the cookies should be handled automatically within the session, correct?